# ListView row highlight when data changes

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` in which data is streaming (changing). I want to just highlight the row for a fraction of seconds when the data is changing and then comes back to old state.

any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to automagically do it.

The easiest way out is setting a boolean variable inside the model class you use in your `Adapter`.

So you will end up doing something like this when something changed:

In `your Activity`:

```
/* setProgress will set the boolean variable */
model.setProgress(40);

/* This will make the ListView update */
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In your Adapter in the `getView()` method:

```
ModelClass model = getItem(position);
if ( model.isUpdated() ) {
  viewForTheRow.startAnimation(yourHighlightAnimation);
}
```

Comment: Be carefull with starting animations on a listview row - if you are implementing the best practice of view recycling (as you should to get performance) then the animation will also apply to the following rows in your listview. I ran into this myself recently trying to implement an animation in a row, and ended up using a handler to iterate over the visible listrows and apply animation